# PayPal IPN Response can't insert to database

Tags: php, string, paypal, paypal-ipn

So recently I built a little IPN system based of others and it worked great. I could via sandbox purchase this item and it would send information via IPN to my listener and would insert in to a database. But now when I tried it yesterday, after no change on the files, it won't work. It does send me the IPN and I can store it in a .txt - but that is as much it lets me to do. If I then manually take the response and change the string to that value (from the .txt) it all works. I don't understand why this is and I've tried numerous ways to fix this.

This below is the response I get from paypal (same problem with my adaptive IPN, which worked before)

```
VERIFIED -- cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=15.00&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=UXU2LGHMZ8FQC&tax=0.00&address_street=1+Main+St&payment_date=02%3A36%3A31+Aug+20%2C+2015+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&first_name=Purple&mc_fee=0.74&address_country_code=US&address_name=Purple+Heart%27s+Test+Store&notify_version=3.8&custom=3-2-FRT&payer_status=verified&business=viktor**-facilitator%40yahoo.com&address_country=United+States&address_city=San+Jose&quantity=1&verify_sign=ARlhq6hLAVqXSD5s.6w.I67yISfcA-u87czB5qI9QnD2Y2gKnJ3b.tHb&payer_email=terleto%40yahoo.com&txn_id=3NX1120866247313A&payment_type=instant&payer_business_name=Purple+Heart%27s+Test+Store&last_name=Heart&address_state=CA&receiver_email=viktor**-facilitator%40yahoo.com&payment_fee=0.74&receiver_id=FWCDTECER3V24&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Featured+Status+for+Umper+Dumpar&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=3-2-FRT&payment_gross=15.00&shipping=0.00&ipn_track_id=dfee171e44f44
```

This is my  IPN

```
        <?php
class Paypal_IPN
{
    /** @var string $_url The paypal url to go to through cURL
    private $_url;
    /**
    * @param string $mode 'live' or 'sandbox' 
    */
    public function __construct($mode = 'sandbox')
    {
        if ($mode == 'live')
            $this->_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        else
            $this->_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    }
    public function run()
    {
        $postFields = 'cmd=_notify-validate&' . file_get_contents("php://input");
        $ch         = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->_url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        /* $fh = fopen('result.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $result . ' -- ' . $postFields);
        fclose($fh); */
        function decodePayPalIPN($postFields)
        {
            if (empty($postFields)) {
                return array();
            }
            $post  = array();
            $pairs = explode('&', $postFields);
            foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
                list($key, $value) = explode('=', $pair, 2);
                $key   = urldecode($key);
                $value = urldecode($value);
                preg_match('/(\w+)(?:\[(\d+)\])?(?:\.(\w+))?/', $key, $key_parts);
                switch (count($key_parts)) {
                    case 4:
                        if (!isset($post[$key_parts[1]])) {
                            $post[$key_parts[1]] = array(
                                $key_parts[2] => array(
                                    $key_parts[3] => $value
                                )
                            );
                        } else if (!isset($post[$key_parts[1]][$key_parts[2]])) {
                            $post[$key_parts[1]][$key_parts[2]] = array(
                                $key_parts[3] => $value
                            );
                        } else {
                            $post[$key_parts[1]][$key_parts[2]][$key_parts[3]] = $value;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (!isset($post[$key_parts[1]])) {
                            $post[$key_parts[1]] = array();
                        }
                        $post[$key_parts[1]][$key_parts[2]] = $value;
                        break;
                    default:
                        $post[$key] = $value;
                        break;
                }
            }
            return $post;
        }
        $raw_post_parsed = decodePayPalIPN($postFields); // Now we are decoding it
        /*echo "<pre>";
        print_r($raw_post_parsed);
        echo "</pre>";
        $raw_post_parsed_Text = var_export($raw_post_parsed, true);
        $fh = fopen('result2.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $result . ' -- ' . $raw_post_parsed_Text);
        fclose($fh); */
        if ($raw_post_parsed['payment_status'] === "Completed") {
            if ($raw_post_parsed['payment_gross'] === "15.00") {
                include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../includes/config.php");
                include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../includes/session.php");
                $verify_sign                 = $raw_post_parsed['verify_sign'];
                $payer_email                 = $raw_post_parsed['payer_email'];
                $custom                      = $raw_post_parsed['custom'];
                $custom_exploded             = explode("-", $custom); // Exploding the item into arrays
                $custom_exploded_sound_id    = $custom_exploded[0]; //sound type
                $custom_exploded_purchase_id = $custom_exploded[1]; //sound ID
                $sql                         = "INSERT INTO as_sound_featured (sound_id, purchaser_id, purchaser_email, verify_sign) VALUES ('$custom_exploded_sound_id', '$custom_exploded_purchase_id', '$payer_email', '$verify_sign')";
                if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    $sql2                      = "UPDATE as_sound SET extra='1' WHERE id=$custom_exploded_sound_id";
                    $website_url               = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/";
                    $comment_desc_notification = "Your sound is now featured";
                    $comment_link_notification = $website_url . "audio/item.php?sid=" . $custom_exploded_sound_id;
                    $sql_not                   = "INSERT INTO as_notifications (notification_owner_id, notification_text, notification_link) VALUES ($custom_exploded_purchase_id, '$comment_desc_notification', '$comment_link_notification')";
                    mysqli_query($con, $sql_not);
                    $con->query($sql2);
                } else {
                    $website_url               = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/";
                    $comment_desc_notification = "Featured status for your sound failed";
                    $comment_link_notification = $website_url . "audio/item.php?sid=" . $custom_exploded_sound_id;
                    $sql_not                   = "INSERT INTO as_notifications (notification_owner_id, notification_text, notification_link) VALUES ($custom_exploded_purchase_id, '$comment_desc_notification', '$comment_link_notification')";
                    mysqli_query($con, $sql_not);
                }
            } else {
                $website_url               = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/";
                $comment_desc_notification = "Featured status for your sound failed";
                $comment_link_notification = $website_url . "audio/item.php?sid=" . $custom_exploded_sound_id;
                $sql_not                   = "INSERT INTO as_notifications (notification_owner_id, notification_text, notification_link) VALUES ($custom_exploded_purchase_id, '$comment_desc_notification', '$comment_link_notification')";
                mysqli_query($con, $sql_not);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what failure you are getting and from what specific inputs. E.g. is PayPal returning INVALID, and if so what full URL are you generating and passing it? How does it differ from the case where PayPal returns VALID?

Comment: It's generating verified - so the info COMES to my website and IPN, it's just the information after I've run it through the function and made it an array - it won't let me see it so I can input it in to the database. The whole decodePayPalIPN is so I can make the result in to an array so I in that way can make it to strings to then put in to database, this doesn't happen - It does make it an array and I can save it to .txt using var_export and see it there, but it won't actually let me take the values from the array and put it in to the database..

Comment: "Can't insert into database" is not a problem description, and neither is "won't let me see it". Try harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm, I had blocked all IPs that weren't mine - so that's the problem. It's solved.